# How to Initialize Array of a Certain Size Inside of a Tuple

Tags: c#

I am using the .NET "ValueTuple" NuGet package, for reference. I would like to know how to initialize an array of a certain size (4, for my purposes) inside of a tuple.

What I am trying to do is this: I have 4 pieces of hardware that I need to query and grab data from. There's 15 data points that I want to grab from each device, so I figured an array of tuples with the structure: (dataPoint, hardwareValueForDataPoint[4]) would be the best way to go about it.

I have tried the following:

```
(string, string[]) [] responses = new (string, string[4]);
```

as well as:

```
(string, string[4]) [] responses;
```

which do not work.

Optimally, I would like to have an array of tuples, in which each element would have 2 components: a string, and a 4-element array of strings. If there is a less convoluted way to do this, please let me know!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here - the fact that you're trying to declare an array of the tuples isn't helping either. Just like elsewhere, arrays are simply arrays - there's no "fixed size" part. (The only place that *does* happen is in unsafe [fixed sized buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)

Comment: then for clarification, what is the point of doing something such as: int [] numbers = new int [4] ?

Comment: If you need to enforce the length, especially if you are not the consumer and it could be misused, you should implement a type that presents the devices as individual properties or through an indexer. It could be fixed at 4 or, with the indexer option, it could be initialized with a length *by you* and unchangeable by the consumer.

Comment: That creates an *instance* of the array type, with a length of 4. Every array *object* has a fixed size after creation, but that's not part of the *type* specification.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your edit, here's what I've come up with:

```cs
(string dataPoint, string[] hardwareValueForDataPoint)[] responses =
    new (string dataPoint, string[] hardwareValueForDataPoint)[15];

responses[0].hardwareValueForDataPoint = new string[4];
...
```

#### Edit

As madreflection notes in the comments, this does not enforce the length of the `hardwareValueForDataPoint` array. If that is a requirement for you, you may want to consider something like the following:

```cs
class HardwareItem
{
    public string DataPoint { get; set; }
    public string[] HardwareValuesForDataPoint { get; } = new string[4];
}

// then use it elsewhere like this...
var hardwareItems = new HardwareItem[15];
```

This solution gives you far more flexibility and control (and readability, at least for me) over the former one.